# Determing language of user with delay

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code that determines what language a visitor on a website has and forwards the user to the right page. I want to add a delay of 3 seconds before it forwards the user. Is this posable?

```
<script>
  var lang = window.navigator.language;
  var userLang = window.navigator.userLanguage;
  if(window.location.href.indexOf('/?edit') === -1) {
    if (lang == "sv-SE" || userLang == "sv-SE") {
      window.location.href = window.location.href + "se";
    } else {
      window.location.href = window.location.href + "en";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You can research about [settimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: I had problem with `settimeout`, that's why I'm using `setInterval`

Comment: what is the problem with using setTimeOut?

Comment: @MonikaMangal, if you will use more different stuff with some additional rendering time it will not complete your js till the end and your stuff will be partly broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setTimeout` to trigger a function call after a specified timeout.

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('/?edit') === -1) {
  const lang = window.navigator.language;
  const userLang = window.navigator.userLanguage;
  let pageLang = 'en';

  if (lang == "sv-SE" || userLang == "sv-SE") pageLang = 'se';

  window.setTimeout(() => {
    window.location.href += pageLang;
  }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this `setTimeout` or `setInterval` like:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
// any staff
},3000);
```

For you it will be like:

```
 if (lang == "sv-SE" || userLang == "sv-SE") {
setTimeout(function(){ 
      window.location.href = window.location.href + "se";
},3000);
    } else {
setTimeout(function(){ 
      window.location.href = window.location.href + "en";
},3000);
    }
```

Comment: setinterval will keep on executing

Comment: Ok. But I had a big problem before, that's why I suggested prev function.

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt, although I agree with you and `setInterval` is more appropriate, changing `window.location.href` will unload the current page. Affect is the same.

Comment: @phuzi That is true..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sleep()` if you don't want to use setTimeout,

```
function sleep( millisecondsToWait )
{
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    while ( new Date().getTime() < now + millisecondsToWait )
    {
        /* do nothing; this will exit once it reaches the time limit */
        /* if you want you could do something and exit */
    }
}


console.log('something');
sleep(3000);
console.log('hello');
```

Comment: This is bad please do not do this. This will cause the browser to hang while it is sleeping, causing it to become unresponsive and potentially causing the browser to kill the page.